# Switch from text links to site icons in the footer

Tags: feature-request, footer

The current site footers include text links to each site:

[image: Screenshot of the current footer]

---

This design has the advantage of removing any doubt about where a link goes, but it:

1. Takes up more space; to compensate normal sites only include links to other normal sites and betas only include links to other betas
2. Is hard to quickly navigate (try to rapidly find "bicycles" in the above screenshot)
3. Rather lacks aesthetic appeal

All the sites already have nice logos designed; is it possible to use those instead of textual links?

[image: Screenshot of an icon-based footer]

---

This fixes the problems I listed above; the only downside I see is increased difficulty for new users who don't know which logo corresponds to which site. I made the icon tooltips for that mockup show the site title, but that requires users to actually try mousing over them:

[image: Screenshot of the mouseover for the Unix icon]

Comment: I failed to find "bicycles" rapidly, but I believe that would have been a lot easier if there was an order to the list, such as alphabetical.  At the moment I can't tell how the sites are ordered...

Comment: @staticbeast That might help. They're currently ordered by launch date (or beta date, for sites that haven't launched yet)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would very substantially increase the download payload of every page we serve, for minor aesthetic reasons. Not likely IMO.

Comment: Really? I thought you stuffed all the images into one graphic to avoid that. I guess I don't get how that sprites image works then

Comment: @michael each site has *its own* images, but you'd be adding a massive sprite of all sites logos.. to every site.

Comment: Maybe you could implement something like the StackExchange Dropdown that is in the header, for the footer. It would just hold a list of all the sites. No need to load any images, it would just organize the links and take up less space.

Answer (score 0):

Loads of icons put together: It is not a good idea, IMO.

Comment: Any particular reason? Jeff had a good point about download size in [his answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72294/switch-from-text-links-to-site-icons-in-the-footer/72295#72295), but I assume that's not what you're concerned about